# Adding values into a HashMap in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$my = array('hello'=>'hi', 'goodbye'=>'bye');
```

How do I add another element into this array?

I tried:

```
array_push($my, array('submit'=>'send'));
```

How do I add values into a HashMap?

Comment: Your first instinct should *not* be to ask Stack Overflow for such trivial problems. You should sit down and read a book on PHP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please read [the manual on arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). This is a fundamental and incredibly trivial part of developing software in PHP.

```
$my['new key'] = 'new value';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$my['submit'] = "send";

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-push.php) documentation.

Every time you need to do something in PHP you've to first read the documentation.